# What's the difference between "teacher" and "professor"?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns, formality

Is one more formal then the other?

Comment: Related (dupe?): [Professors and Students](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8758/).

Comment: @RegDwight, tough call, the question isn't a dupe, but the accepted answer to that question also answers this one...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Teach is including a more general concept.

According to Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English

**Teacher**:

> someone whose job is to teach, especially in a school

**Professor**:

> *American English*: a teacher at a university or college
>
> *British English*: a teacher of the highest rank in a university department

To see academic degrees visit [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_degree).

Also you may find it interesting to know:

- **teacher**   someone who teaches as their job, especially in a school :  a high school teacher
- **principal**  ( also   headteacher   British English )   the teacher who is in charge of a school or college :  The teacher sent him to the principal’s office.
- **tutor**   someone who gives private lessons to one student or a small group of students. In Britain, a tutor is also a teacher in a university :  They hired a tutor to help him with his English.  |  Your tutor will help you find a subject for your essay.
  lecturer   someone who teaches in a university or college :  University lecturers aren’t very well paid.
- **professor**   a teacher in a college or university. In Britain, a  professor   is a high-ranking university teacher, especially one who is head of a department :  She was professor of linguistics at Cambridge University.
- **instructor**   someone who teaches a sport or a practical skill such as swimming or driving :  He works as a ski instructor in the winter.  |  a driving instructor
- **coach**   someone who helps a person or team improve in a sport :  a professional tennis coach
- **educator**   especially American English   formal   someone whose job involves teaching people, or someone who is an expert on education :  Most educators agree that class sizes are still too big.
- **trainer**   someone who teaches people particular skills, especially the skills they need to do a job :  a teacher trainer  |  Many companies pay outside trainers to teach management skills to their staff.
- **governess**   a woman who lived with a family and taught their children in past times :  As a governess, Charlotte Brontë received twenty pounds a year.

Comment: My experience of "tutor" in en-gb is a bit different. Yes, it covers those who give private lessons, but in both my secondary school and my university I had someone designated as my tutor who was a person I could go to for non-academic support.

Comment: @Manoochehr - All good, but I've generally heard "headmaster" where you have "headteacher".

Comment: In the US, many private schools use "headmaster" in place of "principal".  (My own high school, despite being public, used the title "headmaster" as well, and this was widely seen as a bit pretentious.)

Comment: @Henry *Headmaster / Headmistress* is not at all pretenious in British English - it's just the normal title.

Answer (score 4):

*Professor* is more specific of *teacher*, as it is used when referring to a teacher of the highest rank in a college or university.

Informally, *professor* is used to refer to any instructor, especially the specialized ones.

**<sub>[Reference: the *New Oxford American Dictionary*.]</sub>**

Comment: Exactly: You typically wouldn't say *primary school professor*, nor would you say *university teacher*.

Comment: @Benjol: Where I am from, you are called *instructor* at the university level unless you have earned your PhD.

Comment: I think "university teacher" is sometimes used, but in most institutions there's probably no actual job title called a "teacher". As the original poster says, note that a "professor" isn't just any old university teacher, though: it's a specific title implying a specific rank within the department/university, as are "lecturer", "senior lecturer", "reader" etc.

Comment: @Neil Coffey - While that's true from a title standpoint, the term *professor* is used in some regions as a general term to refer to anyone teaching at a university level.  E.g. I would find it extremely odd to say *my math lecturer* instead of *my math professor* regardless of the standing of the actual person in the dept.

Comment: Ah OK -- now I think about it more, I think there's a US/UK difference as well (I think in the UK, "tutor" or "lecturer", depending on the function, may be more common if the person isn't actually a professor).

Comment: In the Korean education system, a 'professor' is anyone who teaches in a University, regardless of qualifications. For that reason, one should refer to a Korean Professor with a PhD as 'Doctor Kim', rather than 'Professor Kim' since that shows respect for their more senior title.

Comment: @NeilCoffey In the UK, it would be an **insult** to call a *professor* anything other than *professor*. Consequently any other university 'teacher' would be called a *lecturer*, *tutor*, or other appropriate title.

Comment: @TrevorD when using it as a *title*, I agree that somebody with the rank of professor would be called 'professor'. Whether they're insulted or not is their business, but I would posit that in general they would be referred to by that title simply because... that's their title. As far as the other informal use I mention, if you're suggesting that e.g. students consistently refer to a tutor who happens to hold a professorship as "my maths professor" and never "my maths lecturer", I think observation will struggle to bear that out.

Comment: @NeilCoffey Thanks. Maybe I misunderstood your previous comments. I was referring to when addressing the professor in person. As to how students refer to their professor-lecturers, I'm sure the terminology is not always polite in any case, and that you are probably correct: it's over 40y since I was at university!

Answer (score 2):

Professor is also a rank, and a title, in the American university system and as such, confers status on its recipients.  There are lots of "instructors" and "lecturers" and "graduate assistants" who teach and publish original research who would love to be called "professor."  So yes, "professor" is more formal than "teacher."  In any sort of professional setting, for example in asking for the referral of an article or seeking university employment, I would be very careful to refer to the professor I'm mailing as "Professor" and not "teacher", so as not to seem overly familiar.

Answer (score 1):

A ***professor*** is one who teaches in a university or college whereas a ***teacher*** is the one who teaches in high schools and comprehensive schools.

Comment: There are many who teach (or research) in universities whose greatest ambition is to become professors.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a 'teacher' is someone who teaches you anything. 'Professor' is a specialist in a field of study and teaches by profession.

A mother can be a teacher but not a professor (unless she is falls into the category mentioned above).

Comment: Yes, a mother can be a teacher (as can anyone), but the context here refers to professionals, and being a *teacher* (e.g. *schoolteacher* is a profession). In British English, *professor* is a specific title and status for the head of a university department.